# trouble finding an appropriate statistical analysis for my model

Tags: stata

i am looking for an appropriate command on STATA to run it, 
hypothesis:
PREDICTORS

parent's social class

(High education x below lower-white collar

High education x professional

Low education x below lower-white collar

Low education x professional)

MEDIATORS

they have the knowledge to help kids on their homeowrk (Binary mediator 1)

They would want their kids to attend university (Bianry mediator 2)

They know how to nurture their kids (Binary mediator 3)

OUTCOME

All then contributes to kids' social mobility

(High education x Low occupation

High education x High occupation

Low education x High occupation

Low education x Low occupation )

Which statistical model should I use for models like this ? (i.e. which commands in STATA should I use) I have thought of using multivariate logistic regression to run it, but the mediators are getting in the way? I dont know how to analyse mediators with multivariate logistic regression In the past I have only learn multilevel modelling, survival analysis, logistic and multiple regressions. So I would appreciate simple explanations. Thank you